# vector insert() error: vector iterator offset out of range

Tags: c++, vector

For some reason this isn't working for me.  It gives me the vector iterator out of range error.

```
directory_entry TDE("Path");
vector <directory_entry> Temp;
Temp.push_back(TDE);

User_Data->DPath.insert(User_Data->DPath.begin(), Temp.begin(), Temp.end());
```

But, this works,

```
vector <directory_entry> DPath;
directory_entry TDE("Path");
vector <directory_entry> Temp;
Temp.push_back(TDE);

DPath.insert(DPath.begin(), Temp.begin(), Temp.end());
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with User_Data->DPath because I can push/pop and access elements in it.  But for some reason I can't seam to be able to use insert on it without getting out of range errors.

Does anyone know why this might be?

**edit:** A popup emerges, debug assertion failed.  It gives me a line in the vector header file, 1111, and a message "Expression: vector iterator out of range".  If I make sure that there is at least one element in User_Data->DPath, and then start at .begin+1, I get "Expression: vector iterator+offset out of range" and it gives me line 157 of the vector header file.

**edit:**  You are all probably right.  The g_new0 function does the memory allocation http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-new0

> struct_type : the type of the elements to allocate. n_structs : the
>   number of elements to allocate. Returns : a pointer to the allocated
>   memory, cast to a pointer to struct_type.

```
typedef struct {
    vector <directory_entry> DPath;
}State;

static gboolian select_dir (ClutterActor *actor, ClutterEvent *event, g_pointer data){
    State *User_Data = (State*)data;

    directory_entry Temp(Path);
    User_Data->DPath.push_back(Temp);

    ...
    return TRUE;
}


int main( argc, char*argv[]){
State *data = g_new0 (State, 1); 

...  

 g_signal_connect(Cluter_Actor, "button-event", G_CALLBACK(select_dir), data)

 ...

 clutter_main();
 g_free(data);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It may help if you could post the error message. Also, if you are copying the whole vector you might consider *copy and swap* idiom or the assignment operator.

Comment: We would need to know how User_Data is initializing the vector because all this code looks valid.

Comment: Hope you have allocated memory to User_Data. Also, please post the code from the constructor of User_Data or post the structure itself.

Comment: Can you post the `g_new0` source as well? This looks ominous. If `DPath` is a vector it needs to be properly *constructed*. Assigning memory is not enough.

Comment: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-new0.  I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced with this type of thing.  How should I construct the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g_new0` is not a drop-in replacement for `new`

`new` does two things: allocates memory for an object, and calls the object's constructor. `g_new0` only does the first, allocating memory. You need to call the object's constructor explicitly if you want to use `g_new0`. This is done using "placement new":

```
State *data = g_new0 (State, 1); 
new (data) State;  // placement new - calls the constructor
```

The reason calling `State`'s constructor is important is that it in turn calls the constructor of the `vector<directory_entry>` member of State, and this is what initializes the vector. Without initializing the vector properly, you cannot use it.

Note that since you are calling the constructor explicitly, you will also need to call the destructor explicitly before freeing the memory:

```
data->~State();  // call destructor
g_free(data);    // free the memory
```

---

Is there a reason you are using `g_new0` instead of just `new`?

```
State *data = new State;
...   // use data
delete data;
```

Comment: I just tried both `State *data = new State`, and `State *data = g_new0 (State, 1); 
new (data) State; `, but when my program starts I get an access violation error reading at memory location ...  I'm using g_new0 per some examples in the "clutter cookbook".  Maybe I should mention that I'm using the C version of clutter.  I don't know if that makes any difference.  I'll have to go over my code and do some more thinking and research, but I need to get some sleep.  Thank you very for your help.